# Serverless package separately or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture, serverless

If I want to deploy my serverless project, should I package it individually? or should I not?

```
# serverless.yml
package:
  individually: true
```

Also, please tell me why.

Comment: If you have multiple functions with completely disjoint code-bases then package them individually and specify what the include in each one. Otherwise you end up deploying code which is never used.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=214756